# Ninject + Poller: Get Session based on Tenant

Tags: c#, service, ninject, polling, multi-tenant

I'm using NInject in a multitenant setup where I'm setting up *n* amount of pollers.

For each thread in the service class, I want to have each my bound classes to get an NHibernate session dependent on the tenant being used in the thread(the created poller). I've got something similar already in use for the web side of things where I've bound it to a session variable in the request and let the ISession.

Sample code follows:

In the service init class....

```
        ////Tenant is a static ThreadLocal, Helper gets session for right tenant...
        kernel.bind<ISession>().ToMethod(Helper.getSession(Poller.Tenant).WhenClassHas<UseTenant>(); 

        //for each tenant, start thread{
          this.Poller = new Poller(kernel, s.tenantKey);
                //// Clean up from an unsafe shutdown
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    this.Poller.CleanUpFromShutdown();
                })
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    this.PollerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
                    this.Poller.StartPolling();
                });
            }
```

Simplified poller class

```
public class Poller{
                public static ThreadLocal<tenant> ten = new ThreadLocal<tenant>(); 
                public static Tenant Tenant{
                    get{
                        return ten.Value(); 
                    }
                    set{
                        ten.Value = value; 
                    }
                }

                public IKernel kernel; 

                public Poller(Kernel kernel, int tenantKey)
                {
                    Tenant = kernel.Get<TenantService>().getTenantbykey(tenantKey); 
                    this.kernel = kernel; 
                }

                public void StartPolling()
                {
                    do{
                    //Attaches FooService each respective tenant session factory 
                    var kernel.Get<FooService>().GetAllFoos(); 
                    //do business logic
                    //then sleep until next poll interval
                    }while(NotCanceled)
                }
            }
```

EDIT:Noticing I didn't really use a question.

Is seems like there would be a better way to do this than binding to ThreadLocal.

Also, in the StartPolling() and CleanUpFromShutDown(), I need to reset the tenant before using any of their respective sessions.

Comment: What's exactly the question? In that code you seem to get a session depending an the tenant already!

Comment: It does to work(though I needed to reset the teneant in  StartPolling()). The use of the static threadLocal just seems clunky.

Comment: It looks like you're giving too much power to the threads themselves, though it's difficult to tell precisely what they're supposed to be doing based on what you've posted.  It seems like you are using NInject to have your polling service monitor an arbitrary number of threads that are already existing when your polling service starts.  Is that accurate?

Comment: Sorta. There are no existing threads when the service is off. On service startup, it spins up n threads, where n the number of tenants. Since each thread will execute in a tenant sensitive context, it needs to get respective session through ninject.